# React fetch img from slow api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise, flux

I am sure that my question is obvious but I cannot find simple answer anywhere. I am not familiar with redux/flux so I don't know if I need to learn them to achieve my goal. 
I get from my server urls to images I need to display on the component. I want to display loader till the image is fetched. 
What is the best (and easiest) way to do that? Is necessary to use flux/redux? 
May I use just fetch(image_URL).then... promise?

For now on just call url while rendering img html tag:

```
{this.props.data.images.map(img=>{
return(
  <img src={img.url}/>
)})
```

how to manage async of this task? I already use apollo to fetch local db data. May I use apollo for fetching external data?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to define a loading flag and use it to determine if the loader should be rendered. It seems that your fetch logic somewhere else but the idea is the same.

```
class YourComponent() extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({isLoading:true});
        fetch('image_URL')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                images: res.images,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading , images} = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return <YourLoaderComponent />
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {images.map(img => <img src={img.url} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a use of **onLoad** react callback on the `<img/>` tag.

### Tutorial:

Define React Component `<LoadedComponent />` which will be a spinner.

Then you can define another React Component `<ImageComponent />` which will have a default `imageLoaded` state set to false.

If `imageLoaded` is `false`, `<ImageComponent/>` will render `img` with `width` and `height` `0px`.

The `<img />` tag has `onLoad` binding to function `imageLoaded()` which then sets the `imageLoaded` state to true. When the state changes `onLoad`(when image finished loading) of `<img/>`, `<ImageComponent/>` automatically rerenders and it renders only `<img/>` with normal width and height.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const LoaderComponent = () => (
  <img
    width="300"
    height="300"
    alt="Loading spinner"
    src="http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif"
  />
);

const hiddenImageStyle = {
  width: 0,
  height: 0
};

class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };
  }

  imageLoaded() {
    this.setState({
      loaded: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loaded) {
      return(
        <div>
          <img alt="Cat" src={this.props.url} width="300" height="300" />
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          alt="Cat"
          src={this.props.url}
          width="300"
          height="300"
          onLoad={() => this.imageLoaded()}
          style={hiddenImageStyle}
        />
        <LoaderComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const imagesUrls = [
  "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4200/34055408873_e9bf494e24_k.jpg",
  "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4536/37705199575_ded3cf76df_c.jpg"
];
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {imagesUrls.map((url, index) => (
          <ImageComponent key={index} url={url} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here you can see a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zwz9o84kn3
If you have a good Internet speed you will probably not notice the spinner. To see the spinner, the best is to open preview of the sandbox in a separate tab
[image]

and then open chrome dev tools and in the Network tab check `disable cache` and set a preset to `Slow 3G` [image]

After refreshing you will notice loadining spinner, until the image will load